# Accessing items in Javascript Node List to alter image

Tags: javascript, image, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to create the same effect of CSS Hover but with Javascript code (for the purpose of learning Javascript and for future use). So on mouseover, I would like the individual image to increase opacity.

The code I have written below does not work. Please see comments for explantion regarding what I am trying to do;

```
<script>
//gets all img tags (qu.20)

var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img")

// Create new element with id "newNode" for the individual node to go into

var node = document.body.createElement("newNode")

// Add the new element into the html document

document.body.appendChild(newNode)

// Attach var i to the individual nodes and set src of new element as that node

function overImage () {
    for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("newNode")
    document.body.newNode.src = images.item(i)  
    }
}

// function to create a new class with same attributes as original when mouse leaves image

function leaveImage () {
    for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("newNode")
    document.body.newNode.src = images.item(i)
    document.body.newNode.className = " leave"
    }
}

</script>

<html>
<img src="image1.gif" onmouseover="overImage()" onmouseout="leaveImage()" alt="image" />
<img src="image2.gif" onmouseover="overImage()" onmouseout="leaveImage()" alt="image" />
</html>

<style>
img { opacity:0.5; }
#newNode { opacity:1; }
#newNode.leave { opacity:0.5; }
```

As an alternative, this code works but only on all images (ie. they all change opacity together, not individually.

```
<script>
 function overImage () {
var selectImage = document.getElementsByTagName("img")
for (var i=0; i<selectImage.length; i++) {
selectImage[i].className = " over"
}
}

function leaveImage () {
var selectImage = document.getElementsByTagName("img")
for (var i=0; i<selectImage.length; i++) {
selectImage[i].className = ""
}
}
</script>

<style>
img { opacity:0.5; }
.over { opacity:1; }
</style>
```

Answers in Javascript only please with explanations. No jquery

Comment: What do you want to use to identify a particular image? Will you add an `id`? By existing `src` attribute? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a much simpler manner, check this example:

```js
var f = function(e) {
  
  // the event target, can be any element in the page at this point
  var t = e.target;
  
  // check if the event target is an img element
  if(t.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
    
    // then toggle its active class
    t.classList.toggle('active');
  }
}

// add listeners to the window (or on whatever image container you have)
addEventListener('mouseover', f /* call this function f on mouseover */, false);
addEventListener('mouseout', f, false);
```

```css
img { opacity: .5; }
.active { opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<img src='http://i.imgur.com/kk7fJccs.jpg'/>
<img src='http://i.imgur.com/kk7fJccs.jpg'/>
<img src='http://i.imgur.com/kk7fJccs.jpg'/>
<img src='http://i.imgur.com/kk7fJccs.jpg'/>
<img src='http://i.imgur.com/kk7fJccs.jpg'/>
```

This code is going to work no matter how many images you add after this. It eliminates for you to add calls to your JS functions (whose names you may choose to change) to the HTML, the need for messing with the DOM from JS, the need for looping in the JS. And as far as the CSS is concerned, it's not using ids for styling, so it's avoiding specificity issues.

Comment: Ana - Thank you for this solution. It worked perfectly. I hope to be able to write such eloquent code one day.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue appears to be right at the top, `document.body.createElement("newNode")` will give you a `TypeError: undefined is not a function`. The *createNode* method is on the *#document* node, not a *HTMLElement*.

Next, you create nodes by tag name, there is no such tag `<newNode>`, maybe you meant to create an `<img>`

```
var node = document.createElement("img");
```

Now you need to assign the *id* attribute to it,

```
node.setAttribute('id', 'newNode');
```

Next, you have to append `node` to your document tree (you're currently trying to append an undefined variable `newNode`)

```
document.body.appendChild(node);
```

Finally, your two functions `overImage` and `leaveImage` have several problems of their own;

- They are performing `document.getElementById` but not remembering the result, instead trying to go through the *DOM tree* in an unusual way **and also** you're trying to assign a node as a *src*, when you probably want to assign a *String*

  ```
  // outside loop
  var node = document.getElementById("newNode");
  // inside loop
  node.src = images.item(i).src;
  ```
- They loop over all of `images` each time, meaning you will always finally end up with `node`'s *src* pointing at the value from the last item in `images`

Try linking up these listeners using [`foo.addEventListner(type, event_handler)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) where `foo` is a reference to each node you want to attach the `event_handler` to. This will let you access the *mouseover* or *mouseout* event in more detail, especially if `event_handler` looks at it's first argument which will be the *event* itself, or `this` which will be the node which invoked the handler.

---

Always check your console as the first step in debugging, it'll usually let you quickly narrow down your issue to the exact line with the problem

Comment: Paul S - thank you for the corrections and detailed explanations.